# Deprecated gcloud sql instances import

Tags: sql, gcloud

I am importing a sql from my bucket into my sql instance. The problem is that I get a Warning, which tells me:

> WARNING: This command is deprecated and will be removed in version 205.0.0. Please use gcloud sql import sql as an alternative.

I'm searching the google documentation for gcloud sql import sql, but I can't find anything about that alternative, I always get the command:

```
gcloud sql instances import
```

The problem is that that command is the one I use and the one that is deprecated. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/instances/import

Does anyone know what the documentation is or what the new alternative is?  Thank you very much.

Comment: All the parameters are same just use "gcloud sql import sql" instead of "gcloud sql instances import". Here is the documentation https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/import/sql

Comment: @MuhammedImranHussain thank u very much! a lost day to find that! Can you put it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @MuhammedImranHussain, the new documentation is here:

[Google Documentation](http://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/import/sql)